# How to charge pay pal customers manually

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Is that possible to charge paypal customer manually. I can do it like user get redirected to paypal to confirm all the details but i do need that user allow my system to charge him every month without any confirmations from his side. 
Currently i'm using the same approach as listed [Paypal .Net Sdk example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-asp-net-mvc/)

But it doesn't have such a func to manually charge a user. If someone could chare links it'd be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, with regular Paypal payments that is not allowed. You could use Paypal subscriptions. Check the [Paypal developer API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/)

Comment: @bradbury9 If user payment cost can vary from month to month, there are no way to use pay pal for manually trigger payments, is that right?

Comment: Not without the user getting redirected to Paypal to do the actual payment. Otherwise that would be a big backdoor to unauthorized payments (theft)

Answer (score 0):

> without any confirmations from his side.

That would require having a billing agreement on file. There are some reference transactions or "future payments" API solutions that use this, but the feature requires business approval from PayPal.

An alternative that does require confirmation from the buyer would be to send them a PayPal invoice, manually via https://www.paypal.com/invoice/create or programmatically via the [Invoices API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/)